# Firebase and Node,js: Sending emails from user's Gmail?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I am new to Firebase. I have linked Firebase to my React Native app, the Auth part is working and in the SCOPES array I am passing necessary scopes for sending emails `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`.

**The Problem:** On backend I am using Node.js and a Google Cloud project for sending emails, the way I wan this to work is that I will be sending a POST request to backend with the access token of user's account and then using that access token to send emails.

Is this something possible? I am basically using 2 different projects, one Firebase project for Authentication and giving Gmail permission and then another Google Cloud project for sending emails. I have whitelisted the Email sending project in Firebase Auth project.

Is this something possible? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Show your code. Are you trying to send email as a Gmail user (impersonate the user)? Do you have either the user's credentials or a G Suite account (look at Domain Wide Delegation).

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I am using G Suite to send emails and as for user's credentials, isn't the access token or refresh token I get after user authenticates with Firebase enough for sending the email? The access token is going to have the ```gmail.send``` scope so I have permission. The users will not be part of my G Suite organization. It's basically an Android app where users send emails to others from app using their own account.

Comment: What have you tried? post your code and show the problem you are having.